# Cloudinary SDK in sapUI5 application

Tags: sapui5, cloudinary, sap-fiori

I'd like to use something that automatically labels images into an sap Fiori app. I found that **Cloudinary** has an add-on called **Google Auto Tagging** which should suit well for this purpose. So I followed [this](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/javascript_integration) guide to use Cloudinary javascript SDK in my controller files of the webapp, and I installed in my PC the javascript SDK but then I'm not able to import Cloudinary library into my project.

I tried to create a zip with the "cloudinary-core" folder, imported it into my project and include "cloudinary-core.js", but I got the error `Cannot read property 'Cloudinary' of undefined`.

I also tried to include "cloudinary-core.min.js" which should be, from what I understood, the standalone minified version of the library, but had same error.

This is how I'm trying to import the library:

```
/* global cloudinary:true */
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "mdonamcve/libs/cloudinary-core/cloudinary"
], function(Controller, cloudinary) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("mdonamcve.controller.MainTable", {
        
        onInit: function() {
            var cd = new cloudinary.Cloudinary({cloud_name: "demo", secure: true});
        },
        ...
    };
}
```

I checked the path and it's correct, but "cloudinary" remains undefined.

Cloudinary SDK can be used for sap Fiori apps, right? Am I doing something wrong? Are there any alternatives to Cloudinary in case the latter doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Cloudinary doesn't use UI5's way of defining modules there is a high change that `undefined` is passed to `cloudinary`.

The global name of Cloudinary seems to be `cloudinary`. To not overshadow that just pass a slightly different name when defining your controller:

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "mdonamcve/libs/cloudinary-core/cloudinary"
], function(Controller, Cloudinary /* now with a capital C */) {
```

This way the globally available `window.cloudinary` (or just `cloudinary`) should also be available in your controller. `Cloudinary` (with a capital C) will still be undefined and can be ignored.

Reference: [This blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/04/30/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-modules-in-sapui5/).

Comment: By using just `cloudinary` I couldn't use it even if I changed the function parameter with a capital C, everything worked fine with `window.cloudinary`, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to use a Cloudinary add-on which requires signing the request, this is to protect you from others abusing that add-on. The easiest solution might be to use the Upload Widget. You will need to also have an endpoint to one of your servers that signs the request before uploading. Everything should be documented here:
(https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget#signed_uploads)

Comment: My issue was a step before, but after I solved the import problem I *did* use the widget as you suggested, so thank you as well!